# Split with specials character and print string value

Tags: java

```
public class SplitStringobj {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String val1= Start//complete//First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download; 
     String val2= First;
     String[] splitObject = outObject.split("//");
        for(String obj :splitObject) {
            if(outObject.startsWith(obj.toString());
             break;
    }
  }
}
```

As i need below O/P

1. List item
   String val1=Start//complete//First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download
   String val2=First
   Output=First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download
2. List item
   String val1=Start//complete//First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download
   String val2=complete
   Output=complete//First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download
3. List item
   String val1=Start//complete//First//com//upload the dummy123//First//download
   String val2=com
   Output=com//upload the dummy123//First//download

Comment: you should be splitting inObject, not outObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

```java
public static String first_match(String[] str, String toMatch) {
    boolean match = false;
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i].equals(toMatch)) {
            match = true;
        }
        if (match){
            output.append(str[i]);
            if (i != str.length-1) { 
                output.append("//"); 
            }
        }
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

Using the above method for:

```java
String val1 = "Start//complete//First//com//upload//First//download";
String val2 = "First";
String[] splitObject = val1.split("//");

String out = first_match(splitObject, val2);
System.out.println(out);
```

it gives output:

```
First//com//upload//First//download
```

EDIT:
I just realised from the comment that it could be done easier with the following:

```java
public static String firstMatch(String str, String toMatch) {
    int index = str.indexOf(toMatch);
    if (index == -1) return "";
    return str.substring(index);
}

String out1 = firstMatch(val1, val2);
```

EDIT 2:
And here's another one-liner way.

```java
val1.replaceFirst(".*?" + val2, val2)
```

Comment: I didnt think of using indexOf until @user16320675 mentioned first occurrence of word, because I was preoccupied with the String[] from split("//")